# How to change datagridview column date format dd/mm/yy to yy/mm/dd when inserting into datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datagridview, insert

I am using C# and I have a column called Date in datagridview In that column date format is in dd/mm/yy. But I want to convert this format into yy/mm/dd when inserting this data to MySQL table

I am a newbie to programming and really need your help...

I have tried using this code but not worked...

```
INSERT INTO tbltracksidescript VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value + "','dd/MM/yy'), '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 2"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 3"].Value + "','" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 4"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 5"].Value + "','" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 6"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 7"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 8"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 9"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 10"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 11"].Value + "','" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 12"].Value + "', '" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column 13"].Value + "');";
```

Comment: Provide the code please

Comment: What the type of your mysql column? Can you post table structure here?

Comment: it is in date type